# turn a number in an element of a string into a coefficient python

Tags: python

First time asking a question here.  I spent a good amount of time searching Stack Overflow and the Google machine to no avail, but maybe I have yet to search for the right thing.  Anyways, the context is, I am just getting into programming, and specifically Python.  I am mostly trying to write stuff for fun to teach myself at this point.

And right now, I am trying my hand at writing **a molecular weight calculator**.

So far I have

- turned the raw_input into a list
- split it by upper case letters so that I could cover the whole periodic table (There are a few that overlap which I try to correct for).

The number (or coefficient) of a particular atom is kept with the element in the list.

- then I turn each atomic symbol (the elements of the list) into its corresponding atomic weight.
- I turn it into a float
- and then sum the list.

I want to use that number (the atomic coefficient) as a coefficient to multiply with the molecular weight, but so far, any atomic coefficient is added on as the last digit of the float. **So I would like to know if there is any way to keep the coefficient, and then multiply it with the value of the atomic weight within each element of the list**.

here is the code I have so far:

```
import re

print
input_mw = raw_input("enter a molecular formula: ")
print

print
print input_mw 
print

# turn the user's mw input into a list split by uppercase letters.

lst_mw = re.sub( r"([A-Z])", r" \1", input_mw).split()

# turns the atomic symbols into their corresponding atomic weight values in the list.

for n,i in enumerate(lst_mw):
    lst_mw[n] = i.replace('H', '1.008')

for n,i in enumerate(lst_mw):
    lst_mw[n] = i.replace('C', '12.011')

for n,i in enumerate(lst_mw):
    lst_mw[n] = i.replace('O', '15.999')

for n,i in enumerate(lst_mw):
    lst_mw[n] = i.replace('Cl', '35.45')

# Attempt at a potential bug fix.

for n, i in enumerate(lst_mw):
    lst_mw[n] = i.replace('12.011l', '35.45')


# turn the values of the list into floats

float_mw = map(float, lst_mw)

print
print float_mw
print

# Sum the list.

output_mw = sum(float_mw)

print
print output_mw
print
```

And here is a sample input/output from terminal:

```
$ python mw_regex_test.py 

enter a molecular formula: CHO


CHO


[12.011, 1.008, 15.999]


29.018
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, to get your list of symbols and coefficients:

```
lst_mw = re.findall(r"([A-Z][a-z]?)(\d*)", input_mw)
                    # ^ single uppercase and optional second lowercase
                                 # ^ as many digits as available
```

This will give you a list of two-tuples `[(symbol, coeff), ...]`, e.g.

```
[('H', '2'), ('O', '')]
```

and handles e.g. `Cl` without any fuss.

Next, rather than all of the `replace`s to swap string for string then separate conversion to float, you can neaten things with a dictionary lookup:

```
weights = {'C': 12.011, 'H': 1.008, 'O': 15.999, 'Cl': 35.45} # etc
```

Now we can go straight from a pair of strings to a product of float and integer:

```
float_mw = []
for symbol, coeff in lst_mw:
    weight = weights.get(symbol, 0.0) # assume zero if unknown
    number = int(coeff) if coeff else 1 # one if not specified
    float_mw.append(weight * number)
```

A few examples:

```
H2O
[('H', '2'), ('O', '')]
[2.016, 15.999]
18.015

HCl
[('H', ''), ('Cl', '')]
[1.008, 35.45]
36.458

CH4
[('C', ''), ('H', '4')]
[12.011, 4.032]
16.043

C2H5OH
[('C', '2'), ('H', '5'), ('O', ''), ('H', '')]
[24.022, 5.04, 15.999, 1.008]
46.069

NH3
[('N', ''), ('H', '3')]
[0.0, 3.024] # note 'N' not in weights therefore 0.0
3.024
```

Comment: Thanks, jonrsharpe, I learned a lot from your answer, and it totally worked.  In the future I will try to incorporate dictionary lookups and that awesome regex syntax too.  Also, thanks to @JanVlcinsky for formatting my question.

Comment: @Tuor no problem - I find [regex101.com](http://regex101.com/r/dZ2sU4) very useful for regular expression development and testing, it does highlighting and explanations.

Comment: jonrsharpe, thanks for the recommendation. I took a look at it, and it will definitely be a resource I will use. If I understand correctly, a regex is useful in that you can specify a pattern, and then search for that pattern in a list or string. So, is it possible to use a list or a string **as** **the** pattern in a regex? From what I understand, it is not.

Comment: @Tuor it's not clear what you're asking. All patterns are strings, with defined tokens and formats. You could have a list of string patterns and iterate through it.

Comment: jonrsharpe, Sorry for the lack of clarity. Say I wanted to take a user's input, and use that as my pattern to compare against another string. An example would be, finding DNA palindromes:`dna_input = raw_input('enter sequence: ')` then I would have to turn that string into the `reverse_compliment`, and then put that input into the regex to compare the original sequence with its reverse compliment to find the palindromes. `dna_regex = re.findall(r"[dna_input]", reverse_compliment)` Is this possible? This probably doesn't make a lot of sense. I should ask it in a new question.

Comment: @Tuor I don't quite follow what you're trying to do, and *"how do I...?"* questions are not a good fit for SO. However, it's certainly possible to take user input and create a pattern from it.

Comment: jonrsharpe, yeah, you are right. I deleted the question, and I will go read up on it. I apologize.